# How can I derive force vectors from velocity vectors?

Tags: xna, physics

I'm making a 2d shooter ala Geometry Wars. I've got my own simple physics at work driving the background grid and all my entities. To move anything in the world I apply a Vector2d force to it. The 'engine' calculates the resulting acceleration and therefore the velocity.

I am trying to port some code I found which implements the classic 'Boids' flocking algorithm, but the code I have works by calculating the Boids' velocities directly, so If i use it as is, it bypasses my physics engine. How I can translate the velocity vectors into force vectors that I can apply to the Boids and which will result in the proper velocities via my physics engine.

Comment: One question to your question: are your bodies capable of theoretically infinite accelerations? If yes, then if the algorithm tells an entity to change its velocity from _v0_ to _v1_, you can compute the acceleration as _a_ = (_v1_ - _v0_ )/dTime .Then you can apply the _F_ = _m_ * _a_ force to that entity and it will have this velocity at the next time step. But, there's another problem: what integration method do you really use? Depending on your update logic and integrator, this simple approach might not work. I assumed a simplistic explicit integrator logic (e.g. Euler).

Comment: If you have velocity, mass and time: Force = (mass * velocity) / time.

Answer (score 6):

It depends how your physics engine works, but you can probably use [Newton's second law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion):

```
F = m × a
```

Where `m` is the mass of the object and `a` is its acceleration (a vector). The acceleration is the `dv/dt` derivative, which can be approximated by dividing the change in velocity by the timestep:

```
F = m × (velocity - previous_velocity) / timestep
```

Of course this only works reliably if the force you're applying is the only one affecting the entity. Otherwise you may experience numerical inaccuracies.

Comment: Be careful about using × for 'times' - a lot of people will (understandably) interpret that as 'cross product'...